# Rails 3.1 - Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a basic Rails application.  I couldn't get some javascript to fire off so I added an alert to my application.js file just to see if the js is working at all.  Here is the code:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

alert("hello");
```

Here is the code in my application.html.ert:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <title>KidsCash</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 </head>
 <body> 
 <%= yield %> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

This code is not getting fired off.  What do I have to do to enable js in a Rails application.  Am I missing a setting or something else.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

*** Maybe this will be of help.  This is the first project that I have created without using `rails new project`.  I created a .rvmrc file, and then ran `rvm --create ruby-2.0.0-p0@gemset`.  I then created the project with `rails new .`.  I don't know if this will make a difference.

*** If I create a project with `rails new <project-name>` then everything works fine.  If I created it this other way, then I don't get access to the javascript from the browser.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Please read on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html

Comment: I did read that, but didnt find anything that would help me.  Any other ideas?

Comment: What is the code of your application layout?

Comment: I added it to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a different file to put your code in, and not use `application.js` since it's being generated and re-written. Any other file in the same directory will be automatically included in your compiled `application.js` and should function properly. In sum: create a new .js file in the same dir.

Comment: I originally added it to the kids.js.coffee file.  It still didn't work, so I added to the application.js to try something else.

Comment: try `kids.js` and your code, in the `assets/javascript` directory

Comment: No, this did not help.  It has to be the way I created the project.

Comment: @jhamm lastly, look in your `config/application.rb` file and make sure `config.assets.enabled` is set to `true`, and is not overridden in your environment configuration file

Comment: Again, that did not work.  I created a new project and in the application.js file put the command `alert("Hello");` and the alert worked just fine.  It is only in this project.  It has to be some other configuration.